# Rails Devise save associated model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a User model that I am using devise for. Each User belongs_to a Group. I am trying to find an easy way to set a user's group on sign up - without creating a custom controller to override devise?.

My models look like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

Here's the form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
<%= devise_error_messages! %>

<%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %>

<%= f.label :password %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password %>

<%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
<%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

<%= label_tag :group_name %>
<%= text_field_tag :group_name %>

<%= f.submit "Sign up" %>
```

Since I'm only trying to save this one additional attribute (group_name), I would like to avoid creating a whole new custom devise controller. Is there a way to save a user's group at the model level - with a callback maybe? Or is there a better way to save a group on sign up?

Thanks!

Comment: You should be able to do some sort of collection select, no? http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select

Comment: I'm not really concerned yet about the form (text field vs. collection select). I'm more concerned with how to save the group_name attribute when the new user form gets saved.

Comment: What exactly you want to do with group name? This will create a new group? Or you want to select from existing ones? Why you need that field in this form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already using a customized form as shown above (that is, you're not using the one Devise gives you) there should be no reason you need to override a Devise controller. The group will just be mass assigned along with the other mass-assignable attributes.

(Personally, in terms of user experience, it might be nice to make the group selection a drop down or something, just so that it's usable, but that's just a matter of preference. An autofill might be nice too.)

Comment: The problem is that Group is a separate model so the attribute won't be saved when I save the User form.

Comment: The `user` has a `group_id` though. Or you should change it to have a `group_id`, if these models follow the relationship you specified above.

Comment: Also, @Scott - it sounds like you're a bit confused about how `belongs_to` relationships are stored. The `User` model should have a `group_id` attribute, not a `group_name` attribute. (Unless `group_name` is your foreign key, which I highly doubt it should be.) See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: The User model has a group_id attribute as the foreign key. But the group_name is what the user enters when on sign up.

Comment: I do agree with varatis, yes user enters group_name, but you will save group_id with the user, not group_name, if your goal here is to "select" a group from existing ones. But, if you want to create a new group with this form, this is completely another story.

Comment: Yes, I will save the group_id, but the user will enter the group_name in the form. When the user enters a group name it will always create a new group. I would like to save the group name without having to re-write the devise controller create action. Is there a way to do that?